# Invoking a web new web page with some HTML string to be rendered in that window

Tags: javascript

I have a web page, on that there is a button. When the user clicks the button, I want to invoke a new browser tab and pass some HTML text which will be rendered in that window. Is this possible do through Javascript and if yes, how ?

thanks
kabir

Comment: "Passing some HTML text" can be _extremely_ risky, it'd imply you're letting users open pages with arbitrary HTML on your site which means they'd be able to send each other pages with custom `<script>` tags enabled allowing XSS. What about storing the HTML on your site on another page and passing _data_, are you OK with that?

Comment: `window.open` + `document.write` // no real security risk here then, because direct user input gets displayed, so user could only “hack” themselves. (Once you pass your HTML as GET parameters or _store_ the result somewhere to display it to other users, this becomes a different matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @BenjaminGruenbaum might have a point you should consider.. the answer to your question is as follows:

```
var newWindow = window.open("","Test","width=300,height=300,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
newWindow.document.write('Some string');
```